# Perf sched_stat_sleep issues after reboot

Tags: kernel, permissions, performance, fstab, debugging

I'm using perf's `sched:sched_stat_sleep` on Ubuntu 20.04, and have added the following to the `/etc/fstab`:

```
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug    debugfs defaults 0 0
tracefs /sys/kernel/tracing  tracefs defaults 0 0
```

However, after rebooting the machine, I'm unable to run the `perf` command (for example `perf record -e sched:sched_stat_sleep -e sched:sched_switch -e sched:sched_process_exit -a -g -o perf.data sleep 1`) and it errors out with:

```
event syntax error: 'sched:sched_stat_sleep'
                     \___ can't access trace events
Error:  No permissions to read /sys/kernel/tracing/events/sched/sched_stat_sleep
Hint:   Try 'sudo mount -o remount,mode=755 /sys/kernel/tracing/'
```

Running the following again, does allow me to use perf's setting correctly again.

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/enable
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/sched_schedstats
sudo mount -o remount,mode=755 /sys/kernel/debug/
sudo chmod 755 /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/
```

What's the correct method of setting this up to survive reboots?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out just adding additional `fstab` options helped fix the permission issue:

```
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug    debugfs defaults,mode=755 0 0
tracefs /sys/kernel/tracing  tracefs defaults,mode=755 0 0
```